# Easiest way to use GPU for parallel for loop

Tags: multithreading, language-agnostic, parallel-processing, gpu, gpgpu

I currently have a parallel for loop similar to this:

```
int testValues[16]={5,2,2,10,4,4,2,100,5,2,4,3,29,4,1,52};
parallel_for (1, 100, 1, [&](int i){ 
    int var4;
    int values[16]={-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1};
    /* ...nested for loops */
        for (var4=0; var4<16; var4++) {
            if (values[var4] != testValues[var4]) break;
        }
    /* ...end nested loops */
}
```

I have optimised as much as I can to the point that the only thing more I can do is add more resources.

I am interested in utilising the GPU to help process the task in parallel. I have read that embarassingly parallel tasks like this can make use of a modern GPU quite effectively.

**Using any language, what is the easiest way to use the GPU for a simple parallel for loop like this?**

I know nothing about GPU architectures or native GPU code.

Comment: If your task is a numerical computing task of some kind, or if you can re-cast it as a matrix-math based problem, then you could use MATLAB. New MATLABs support both parallel-for (`parfor` from the Parallel Computing Toolbox) and matrix math on Nvidia CUDA GPUs. Both of these are relatively painless, requiring only modest changes to existing MATLAB code.

Comment: Some more information on what you're trying to actually do here may be helpful. Remember that transferring data from the CPU to the GPU incurs a significant overhead, so GPU computation only gives a performance increase if you're doing a lot of computational work per unit of input data. Calculating the square of each number in a vector is not a good use of GPGPU (hardly any work per unit of data); calculating the FFT of a vector is a good use (lots of work on little data).

Comment: I have several nested for loops, in the innermost loop I am using the loop indices to calculate 16 values and comparing these to the testValues[] array. There shouldn't be any significant memory accessing. Also I'm using an AMD/ATI card (6850).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

as Li-aung Yip said in comments, the simplest way to use a GPU is with something like Matlab that supports array operations and automatically (more or less) moves those to the GPU.  but for that to work you need to rewrite your code as pure matrix-based operations.

otherwise, most GPU use still requires coding in CUDA or OpenCL (you would need to use OpenCL with an AMD card).  even if you use a wrapper for your favourite language, the actual code that runs on the GPU is still usually written in OpenCL (which looks vaguely like C).  and so this requires a fair amount of learning/effort.  you can start by downloading OpenCL from AMD and reading through the docs...

both those options require learning new ideas, i suspect.  what you really want, i think, is a high level, but still traditional-looking, language targeted at the gpu.  unfortunately, they don't seem to exist much, yet.  the only example i can think of is [theano](http://deeplearning.net/software/theano/introduction.html) - you might try that.  even there, you still need to learn python/numpy, and i am not sure how solid the theano implementation is, but it may be the least painful way forwards (in that it allows a "traditional" approach - using matrices is in many ways easier, but some people seem to find that very hard to grasp, conceptually).

ps it's not clear to me that a gpu will help your problem, btw.

Comment: I decided to use OpenCL - the learning curve isn't too bad actually. I found it easier than struggling with libraries that try to convert existing code - the few wrappers I was able to find failed pretty quickly and required GPU programming techniques anyway. Matlab seems to support CUDA only at the moment unfortunately.

Comment: ok, cool.  are you calling from c?  i found that the pyopencl was easier than c - you still program the opencl part the same, but there's less work in preparing the data to send.  but then i am more used to python than c...

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check out array fire.

http://www.accelereyes.com/products/arrayfire

If you use openCL, you need to download separate implementations for different device vendors, intel, AMD, and Nvidia.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [OpenACC](http://www.openacc.org/) which enables parallelism via directives. You can port your codes (C/C++/Fortran) to heterogeneous systems while maintaining a source code that still runs well on a homogeneous system. Take a look into this introduction [video](http://www.openacc.org/content/short-intro-openacc). OpenACC is not GPU programming, but expressing parallelism into your code, which may be helpful to achieve performance improvements without too much knowledge in low-level languages such as CUDA or OpenCL. OpenACC is available in commercial compilers from PGI, Cray, and CAPS (PGI offers new users a free 30 day trial).